# Extrema of a functional

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm interested in computing an extremal for the functional

$J(y)= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} y' \sqrt{1+(y'') ^{2}} dx $

satisfying the boundary conditions $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1, y'(1)=2$.

**My attempt:**

My first attempt was obvious, that is , since $J$ does not depend on $y $ explicitly, there exist a constant $c_{1} $ such that:

$c_{1}= \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}}-\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y'}} $

And since

$\displaystyle \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}}= \frac{y y''}{\sqrt{1+(y'')^2}}$

$\displaystyle \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y'}}= \sqrt{1+(y'')^2}$

We have that

$c_{1}= \displaystyle \frac{y'y'''-(y'')^{2}-1}{(1+(y'')^{2})^{3/2}}$

I tried to solve the equation above but it is quite nontrivial for me, I just know the basics about ODE, for try to solve it I made the change of variable $z=y'$ and I got

$c_{1}(1+z'^{2}z^{2})^{3}=(z^{3}z''-1)^{2}$

However, I still don't see how to solve it if i follow that path :( .

My second attempt was to consider the change of variables

$x=r(\theta)cos (\theta)$      $y=r(\theta)sin(\theta)$

Thus,

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}= \displaystyle \frac{ rcos(\theta)+r' sin(\theta)}{-rsin(\theta)+r' cos(\theta)}$

And therefore,

$\displaystyle \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}= \displaystyle  \frac{2(r')^{2}-r(r''-r)}{(-rsin(\theta)+r' cos(\theta))^{3}}$

Which implies that,

$  y' \sqrt{1+(y'') ^{2}} dx  = \displaystyle \frac{ rcos(\theta)+r' sin(\theta)}{-rsin(\theta)+r' cos(\theta)} \sqrt{1+\displaystyle  \frac{(2(r')^{2}-r(r''-r))^{2}}{(-rsin(\theta)+r' cos(\theta))^{6}}} d \theta$

As you can see, this not improve the situation haha :( .

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.
Since $J$ does not depend explicitly on $y$, he have already said that there existe a constant $c_{1}$ such that

$   \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}} -\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y'}}=c_{1}  $

But, it's also true that since $J$ does not depend explicitly on $x$ there exist a constant $c_{2}$ such that

$\displaystyle y'' \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}} - y' \left( \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}} -\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y'}} \right)-f= c_{2}$

That is, we have that

$\displaystyle y'' \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y''}} - y' c_{1}-f=c_{2}$

Therefore,

$-c_{1}y'- \displaystyle \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y''^2}}=c_{2}$

The boundary condition $y'(0)=0$ implies that $c_{2}=0$, and thus, we only need to solve

$-c_{1}y'= \displaystyle  \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y''^2}}$

This last equation leads to $y''^2=\displaystyle  \frac{1}{c_{1}^2}-1$ . Integrating and using the others boundary conditions we see that $y(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

#### Experimental idea

Set $\sin(u)=\frac{y''}{\sqrt{1+y''^2}}\implies y''=\tan(u)$. Then the Euler-Lagrange equation reduces to $(y'\sin(u))'=c_1+\sqrt{1+y''^2}$, which further transforms to
$$
\tan(u)\sin(u)+y'\cos(u)u'=c_1+\frac1{\cos(u)}
\implies u'=\frac{\frac{c_1}{\cos(u)}+1}{y'}
$$
With $y'=v$ this gives the first order system
\begin{align}
y'&=v,& y(0)&=0,&y(1)&=1\\
v'&=\tan(u),& v(0)&=0,&v(1)&=2\\
u'&=\frac{\frac{c_1}{\cos(u)}+1}{v}
\end{align}
This could be useful as a compact formulation for a BVP solver.

#### Constant solutions

If $c_1+\cos(u)=0$, then this gives a valid constant solutions. Thus $y''=C\implies y=A+Bx+\frac12Cx^2$. This also includes the cases $v=y'=0\implies y=A+Bx$. With the initial conditions the linear functions can be ruled out, the quadratic functions give a solution $y(x)=x^2$. This does not prove that it is the only solution or the optimal among them.

#### One further integration

Assuming that the denominators are not zero or at least not constant zero, combining the last two equations gives,
$$
\frac{v'}{v}=\frac{\sin(u)u'}{c_1+\cos(u)}\implies v=\frac{c_2}{c_1+\cos(u)}
$$
and then
$$
\frac{\cos(u)u'}{(c_1+\cos(u))^2}=\frac1{c_2}
$$
which in principle can be integrated...

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Please check my comment below, considering to delete it, being not sure of it. Thanks.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hi, first of all thank you very much for your answer. I even not had thought in that idea! I need to do a lot of exercises. Once said that, there is no a little mistake in the final equation that you wrote? I think it's $sin(u)$ instead of $cos(u)$  in the numerator.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it's possible because $tan(u)=sin(u)/cos(u)$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can not reconstruct what lead to that kind of mistake, I might at one stage even have "corrected" it to the wrong form.

Answer (score 2):

I) General strategy:

1. OP's functional $J[y]$ is equivalent to
   $$S[y,v,\lambda]~=~\int_0^1\! \mathrm{d}x~L,\qquad L~=~ v\sqrt{1+\dot{v}^2}+\lambda(\dot{y}-v),\tag{A}$$
   with the boundary conditions (BCs)
   $$ y(0)~=~0~=~v(0),\qquad y(1)~=~1,\qquad v(1)~=~2.\tag{B}$$
   Here dot means differentiation wrt. $x$. (To get back to OP's functional $J[y]$ just eliminate the constraint $$\dot{y}~=~v\tag{C}$$ and the [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$.)
2. We next use [Noether's theorem (NT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem):

   - Since $y$ is a [cyclic variable](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_coordinates), the corresponding momentum
     $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}}~=~\lambda\tag{D}$$
     is a constant of motion.
   - Since the Lagrangian (A) has no explicit $x$-dependence, the energy
     $$ E~=~\dot{y}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}}
     +\dot{v}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{v}}
     +\dot{\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\lambda}}-L~=~\ldots~=~
     \frac{v}{\sqrt{1+\dot{v}^2}} +\lambda v
     \tag{E}$$
     is a constant of motion.

   If you don't know NT, you should just check that the total derivatives vanish
   $$ \frac{d\lambda}{dx}~=~0\qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{dE}{dx}~=~0, \tag{F}$$
   by using the [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for the functional (A).
3. Eq. (E) leads to a 1st order ODE
   $$ \dot{v}~=~\pm\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{(E-\lambda v)^2}-1},\tag{F} $$
   which can be [integrated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2FSqrt%5B+v%5E2%2F%28a+v-+b%29%5E2-1%5D%2Cv%5D)
   $$ \pm (x-x_0)~=~\int\!\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{(E-\lambda v)^2}-1}}~=~\ldots \tag{G}$$
   to obtain the inverse function $v\mapsto x(v)$.
4. Eqs. (C) & (G) lead in principle to a solution $x\mapsto y(x)$ with 4 integration constants $(\lambda,E,x_0,y_0)$, which should be determined by the 4 BCs (B).

II) Specific boundary conditions:

1. Eq. (E) with the BC $v(0)=0$ yields $E=0$. Then eq. (F) simplifies to $\dot{v}={\rm const}$, which can be readily integrated to $y(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$. The BCs (B) then yields
   $$y(x)~=~x^2. \tag{H}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint! Although I think I can't use it  because I even not know the Noether's theorem yet :( .

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: thank you very much!